# Image of small dimensions automatically resizes when using Glide Library

Tags: java, android, xml, gif, android-glide

I have an issue with the GIF Resizing.
My GIF dimensions is `136*136` px and I'm trying to load it into an image view (that has its width and height set as `wrap_content`) using Glide library. But the GIF ends up taking the entire screen.
My XML file code snippet looks like below:

```
ImageView
    android:id="@+id/loading_animation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    tools:src="@drawable/gif_loading_animation"
    android:foregroundGravity="center" />
```

And My main activity code looks something like this:

```
Glide.with(getContext())
            .load(R.drawable.gif_loading_animation)
            .asGif()
            .into(loadingAnimation);
```

Is there any solution to avoid resizing without using any hard code parameters width and height.
 :)

Comment: which drawable folder did you put your resource?

Comment: Have you tried using the scaletype on the ImageView?

Comment: And It would be helpful to trace your problem if you provide your whole xml

Comment: @AbuYousuf It's in normal drawable which is default in android studio.

Comment: @HimanshuSinghal This comment is not directly related to qstn. I guess its time to move to new version of Glide 4.7.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using `.override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)`

```
    Glide.with(getContext())
     .load(R.drawable.gif_loading_animation)
     .asGif()
     .override(Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL, Target.SIZE_ORIGINAL)
     .into(loadingAnimation);
```